# What does this flag decline message mean?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

I flagged [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19022886/need-a-regular-expression-for-asp-net-textbox) as very low quality and it was declined. I have had some declined flags but this one came with a message `declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention`.

I dont really understand the meaning of this message. What is it trying to tell in respect to future flags.

(The post has been put on hold as `Off-Topic`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means that you should only flag questions which require a moderator to take action, rather than something the community can handle.

This question isn't "very low quality" because it doesn't have any *formatting or content problems* as such - it's just a terrible format for Stack Overflow and very unclear what they are asking. Someone from the community would probably vote to close this as either "off-topic" or "unclear what you're asking" instead.

Comment: Or you can flag with those types of flags which will kick it into the >3k close queue

Answer (score 7):

I think that you used the wrong flag. The message of the low quality flag is

> This question has severe formatting or content problems. This question
>   is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be
>   removed.

You should use this flag when the question has formatting problems or it's written so bad that it's unclear what the OP actually aks.
The flagged question doesn't

> demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.

and thus it's off topic.