# When is the need for a moderator's attention determined with low quality questions?

Tags: discussion, flags, low-quality-posts, declined-flags

During my daily check of SO, i came across [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19089352/1401094) question,

[image]
So naturally i flagged it as low quality since such questions are impossible to answer.
But for some reason the moderator reviewing the flag declined it.
[image]

The question at hand here, when is a question worthy of flagging for a moderator's attention, should we simply ignore such questions in the future?
If not then what would be the appropriate way to deal with the situation?

Comment: I believe these are flag/vote as off topic because --> must demonstrate a minimum understanding of the problem. I think VLQ flags are very rare and are for horrific formatting problems

Comment: @RichardTingle are all declined flags given the same description automatically ?

Comment: I believe not, but that is a regularly seen description. I believe that one is canned

Comment: This question is readable; it may be off topic and / or too broad, but it does not require deletion by a moderator.

Comment: @PatsyIssa: I do think that the moderators have canned responses available.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I understand that they don't have the time to go through every flagged post, but shouldn't the declined message reflect the reason?

Comment: Also see [Why are the moderators being so strict with quality related flags recently?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160754)

Comment: @PatsyIssa: I think the reason is perfectly clear; don't bother moderators with content that the wider community can handle. Flagging for Off Topic or Too Broad sends the post to the close review queue instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Understood, off topic and too broad  = community, the rest = moderators.

Comment: See also [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/198805/213634) for a recent discussion. I've tried to collect a number of reasons and backgrounds in my answer to it, only some of which are mentioned in the comments here.