# Remove "formatting" from Very Low Quality flag description

Tags: discussion, flags, low-quality-posts

According to [one of our janitors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/160410/minitech), "Very Low Quality" flags are [not meant for formatting issues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198803/why-was-this-very-low-quality-flag-declined#comment630616_198804):

> Very Low Quality flags are not for formatting. Formatting is something
>   that can be fixed, usually in no time.

However, the flag description says right on it that (emphasis mine):

> This question has **severe formatting** or content problems. This
>   question is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need
>   to be removed.

Since it's been interpreted that if there are only formatting problems, that it *is* "salvageable through editing", shouldn't that section be removed? Wouldn't it be better if it read something like this?

> This question has severe content issues that cannot be resolved by
>   editing. This question is actively harmful to the site and requires
>   urgent removal.

Comment: I'd be very curious why that phrase was there to begin with.  As it stands now, it does seem wrong, but maybe it was included for a specific reason.

Comment: +1. I agree with the suggestion but I'd like a different replacement text, more like @shog9 answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your emphasis changes the meaning of the flag. The purpose is to indicate that the issues - whether with formatting *or* content - are *severe*, and cannot be salvaged. That's right: the key part of that flag's description is, **unlikely to be salvageable.** [Anders' answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198803/why-was-this-very-low-quality-flag-declined/198805#198805) is correct.

Indeed, we could probably simplify this flag by replacing the entire first sentence with what it actually *means*:

> This [question|answer] is impossible to read or understand. It is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

I'm a bit hesitant to suggest this though, as there has been *such* a long history of folks misunderstanding this flag; suggesting specific criteria for how the post is supposed to be evaluated is important as an educational tool for the folks using it.

Comment: Could you provide an example where formatting issues _alone_ were enough to make a post "very low quality"?

Comment: I like your suggestion for the replacement text better than the OP's, but I cannot upvote your answer since you appear to think that it is not a good idea to make the change. I think your suggested text gives more accurate guidelines on when this flag is to be set than the existing one, which leads to incorrect flagging, IMO.

Comment: Should 20k+ users vote to delete answers even when they aren’t flag-worthy?

Comment: Sometimes, yeah @adamant. 20k users are granted this privilege with the assumption that they're familiar enough both with the site's rules and *what makes a useful answer* to judiciously cull those that fail to meet either / both criteria.

Comment: That might make a useful answer [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3293/51379) or [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10976/51379), if you have the time.

Comment: I don't at the moment, but if you poke around here this has been discussed dozens of times over the past 8 years @adam

Comment: I don’t get your logic of your last paragraph. You do not wish to use a more clear description of the flag because there has been a long history of misunderstanding the flag? Your suggestion is certainly more specific and makes more sense than the current state. I have no idea how unsalvageable formatting problems would even look like.

Comment: My suggested wording describes a situation in which such a post would need to be removed, @Wrzlprmft - but it doesn't describe what to look for when determining if such a situation exists. "Severe formatting or content problems" isn't much better, but it does at least attempt to give flaggers specific things to look at when evaluating the post; I kinda think we should move further in that direction, or combine the two somehow "this post is unreadable due to severe problems with its formatting, spelling, grammar, etc."

Comment: @Shog9: Fine by me, though I still don’t see why formatting and spelling are in there. If I can identify problems of either kind as such, I can also fix them. How about: “This post is unreadable due to severe problems with its language or structure. It can only be salvaged by its author and may need to be removed”?

Comment: Interet reprts of rscheearch at Cmabrigde uinervtisy aside, it *is* possible for a post to be so badly mangled as to be unintelligible, @Wrzlprmft. Sending stuff through Google Translate is a common way of accomplishing this. Not to mention stuff like folks posting images of code or formulas.

Comment: @Shog9: *it* is *possible for a post to be so badly mangled as to be unintelligible* – I do not doubt that, but then spelling is not the problem anymore or even if it is, it is not recognisable as such. Google Translate may produce horrible English, but I doubt that it makes spelling mistakes. Anyway, *language* should capture all of this. — As for images of codes or equations, if this is what *formatting* refers to, I cannot see anybody understanding the flag text that way, in particular since those *can* be understood and salvaged by others (it’s just excessively tedious).

Answer (score 1):

I think it has to do with a question that is beyond any rescue, if a question is worded so badly and the grammar mangled in such a way that the question itself is unreadable by anyone then formating might be a good reason for closing such a question.

For example let's say you met this:

> ts code no work wy no work? cn u fx? code = fr fnd pm nmbs?
>
> ```
>  public static a(b)
> while(i=+2<b)
>    if(!c(a,b)); return c(a,b) 
> return true
> public static c(d){return a%b}
> ```

Comment: While that's not a bad point, the example you give is more of a _content_ issue. I could format that as the following: "Why doesn't this code work? Can the problem be solved? `code = fr fnd pm nmbs? public static a(b) while(i=+2`", which isn't badly formatted, but definitely has content issues.

Comment: I think you are already having trouble with interpating this as code is for finding prime numbers which you took to mean that code= fr fnd pm nmbs as part of the code itself (hey look at that apparently this code triggers some kind of bug that prevents the hole answer from showing.

Comment: Wow, that's just hilarious, so true. Well then that would read "Why doesn't this code work? Can the problem be solved? What's the code needed for finding prime numbers? `public static a(b) while(i=+2<b)if(!c(a,b)); return c(a,b) return true public static c(d){return a%b}`".

Comment: For example, like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KS5lA.png).